# network segment (powerlan) suddenly unidirectional

Tags: networking, routing

My network looks like follows:
A-B-C-D

- A is an OpenWrt router connected to internet and serves as DHCP (static) and gateway
- B is a powerlan network adapter (netgear powerline) connected over ethernet to A
- C is the other end of the powerlan pair and bridges it to Wifi
- D are devices like laptops, smartphones, ... connected by Wifi to C and get the IP-addresses from A

B and C is to extend the range of the network to distant parts of the house.
Every few days the internet connection drops for all devices connected to C at the same time but not for devices connected to A. To get back to normal, B is unplugged and plugged in again. I managed to get the users to run wireshark in background. My analyses of the captures is:

- The devices D stay connected to the network.
- The devices D receive all packages sent to them are by broadcast (also from devices connected to A directly)
- Packages they send are not received by devices connected to A directly or by servers on the internet (captured "TCP Spurious Retransmissions" with an ack every in the seconds when internet went down)
- D send arp-requests for "Who has (ip-address of A)?" but dont get answer
- D gets arp-requests for them by A and answer them

This is already for a few weeks and only happens every couple of days. Before that there was a wifi repeater instead of B and C but the users of D complained about internet loss the same way but I dont know if this is connected.

Any idea for the reason/solving this or ideas for tests?

I can hardly test myself so instructed one user with at least limited network know how to do the wireshark capture. I cant keep the outage too long else other users would complain too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason by luck and wanted to share:
The problem were electric devices. I.e. everytime the light was switched on, the powerlan connection was disturbed.